# React long press error: cannot read property of splice undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still new to React/JS and am currently working on a mobile website and want to implement a delete without a button. To do so I am using a long press event that allows a user to long-press an input field which then will delete after the time requirements are met.

What I think I should be doing is splice the input field like this:

```
  handleButtonPress() {
    this.buttonPressTimer = setTimeout(() => this.inputs.splice(index, 1), 950);
  }
```

The long-press event functions except that the site receives an error after the time event is met:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined`

```
 | }
  52 | 
  53 | handleButtonPress() {
> 54 |   this.buttonPressTimer = setTimeout(() => this.inputs.splice(index, 1), 950);
     | ^  55 | }
  56 | 
  57 | handleButtonRelease() {
```

I tried using this function but received the same error:

```
  handleButtonPress() {

    const newInput = this.state.inputs
    this.buttonPressTimer = setTimeout(() => newInput.inputs.splice(index, 1), 950);
  }
```

Here is how I'm fully trying to implement this function:

### Edit.jsx

```
import React from 'react'


export default class Edit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleButtonPress = this.handleButtonPress.bind(this)
    this.handleButtonRelease = this.handleButtonRelease.bind(this)

    this.state = { inputs: [], text: ''}
    
    this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this);
  }

  handleButtonPress() {
    this.buttonPressTimer = setTimeout(() => this.inputs.splice(index, 1), 950);
  }

  handleButtonRelease() {
    clearTimeout(this.buttonPressTimer);
  }
    this.setState({ input })}

  render() {
      return (
        <>
            <div
              onTouchStart={this.handleButtonPress}
              onTouchEnd={this.handleButtonRelease}
              onMouseDown={this.handleButtonPress}
              onMouseUp={this.handleButtonRelease}
              onMouseLeave={this.handleButtonRelease}>
                      
             //removed map function of inputs    

            </div>
        </>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

I've removed most of the code here because it's irrelevant to the question. Please note there is a `.map` function for the inputs that are not included in this example. I'm not sure how to move forward from here with this issue.

Comment: what is the line `this.setState({ input })}` supposed to do? it's a syntax error with the unpaired `}`, it's `input` instead of `inputs` and it would be a ReferenceError either way because neither variable exists

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your object keys consistently. Given the constructor:

```
this.state = { inputs: [], text: ''}
```

Only `this.state.inputs` is defined, the `this.inputs` is undefined, similar to the `this.state.inputs.inputs` in following code:

```
const newInput = this.state.inputs
...newInput.inputs
```